# how to access kafka with acl in my storm jar?

Tags: apache-storm

Before I use kafka with no any SASL or ACL，it works fine, now i built SASL_PLAINTEXT for my kafka cluster，how to access my kafka cluster in my storm jar?

My storm version:1.1.0
Kafka version:0.10.1

I use HDP-2.6.3.0-235

any suggestions would be helpful.thanks

Answer (score 0):

These are the steps I followed to get storm running with kafka in a secured environment

1.You need to use hdp specific dependencies for storm to enable the security protocol property

```
<repositories>
        <repository>
            <releases>
                <enabled>true</enabled>
            </releases>
            <snapshots>
                <enabled>true</enabled>
            </snapshots>
            <id>hortonworks.extrepo</id>
            <name>Hortonworks HDP</name>
            <url>http://repo.hortonworks.com/content/repositories/releases</url>
        </repository>

        <repository>
            <releases>
                <enabled>true</enabled>
            </releases>
            <snapshots>
                <enabled>true</enabled>
            </snapshots>
            <id>hortonworks.other</id>
            <name>Hortonworks Other Dependencies</name>
            <url>http://repo.hortonworks.com/content/groups/public</url>
        </repository>
    </repositories>
```

and then include the hdp specific dependency for storm[change it as per your hdp version]

```
<storm-core.version>1.1.0.2.6.2.37-3</storm-core.version>
<dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.storm</groupId>
            <artifactId>storm-core</artifactId>
            <version>${storm-core.version}</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
```

2.Now you need use the security protocol property while creating spouts(it will not be availaible unless using hdp specific repo)

```
spoutCfg.securityProtocol = "SASL_PLAINTEXT";
```

3.Use acl command on your topic by giving the appropriate storm user

```
bin/kafka-acls.sh --authorizer-properties zookeeper.connect=localhost:2181 --add --allow-principal User:storm-user --allow-principal User:zriskcanvas --consumer --producer  --group=* --topic testTopic
```

4.Make sure the storm jaas-conf is getting passed to each node with the user mentioned in ACL